# Change HighStock chart label on changing rangeselector button

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How can I change chart labels (http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#labels) on clicking rangeselector button in Highstock.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please show us what have you tried?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aagrawal/P8eCf/ - Here i tried to assign new value to chart.options.label on chart redraw.

Answer (score 0):

You can set http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.labels.useHTML as true and use formatter http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.labels.formatter to return value in i.e div. Then you tan modify content of labels by jquery.

Comment: I ended up using chart.renderer to draw the text instead of labels and using button click function to capture the event. http://jsfiddle.net/aagrawal/P8eCf/8/